# Invalid WAR error on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

There are some *unanswered* questions about this on SO, but I want to expose my specific scenario 'cause I think it's different to the cases I read already.

My application is a WAR, which is actually just a Flash app launched in a JSP page. I implemented a new feature which causes my client's Tomcat to log:

```
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/Sunnel_BlazeDS]
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/Sunnel_BlazeDS]
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
.
.
.

Dec 17, 2015 3:12:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
.
.
.

Dec 17, 2015 3:12:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
.
.
.

Dec 17, 2015 3:12:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /apache/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/Sunnel_BlazeDS.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Sunnel_BlazeDS]]
.
.
.
```

The new feature only consists of a class that implements ServletContextListener so it starts along with Tomcat and does some work (sending an email). To work it also needs that the client sets up some variables in conf/context.xml.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Environment override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="someone@clientdomain.com" name="mailFrom"/>
    <Environment override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="mail.domain.com" name="mailHost"/>
    <Environment override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="********" name="mailPassword"/>
    <Environment override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="pedro.otero@domain.com" name="mailTo"/>
    <Environment override="false" type="java.lang.String" value="pedro.otero@domain.com" name="mailUser"/>
</Context>
```

I tried either registering the new class in web.xml, or just anotating it with @WebListener and it fails the same way. But the thing is the client sent me all their Tomcat folder, and it works on my machine. So this error only happens on theirs, with the same setup 'cause I just started their Tomcat when I got it without modifying any config.

Would like to add that the new feature I made implied that 3 new jars would be packaged with the WAR. What should I look for in those jars that may cause a problem?

The deploy is made by directly placing the WAR in the webapps folder. The client can deploy any previous version of my WAR. It's just the one with the new feature that breaks.

Comment: your title should specify the problem, not anger.

Comment: I didn't think it would express anger, I'm not angry. To me it just acknowledges the fact that it's been asked many times, some solutions have worked for some, and others still have no answer and it still gets asked...

Comment: I'll be surprised if its the ContextListener itself.  TOmcat is complaining it can't unzip the WAR; you haven't got to the ContextListener yet.  What occurs when you remove all the ConextListiner stuff, same unzip error?

Comment: So when you use exactly the same packed war file, it works perfectly? Are you using the same tomcat and JDK version? Try lowering the logging level of the client's tomcat to DEBUG and see what gets printed.

Comment: Could you post the conf/context.xml file?

Comment: Can you unzip the war file with another zip tool yourself? As tomcat is complaining about it - you might want to look at the problems it has unzipping. Also, consider file locks in temporary and work folders in case this happens on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the `conf/server.xml` file of both Tomcats: yours and the problematic one. Pay attention specially to the `docBase` attributes, and check if it points to a readable, valid WAR file.

Comment: You're right, but I pasted it wrong. It's indeed as you say on my machine. Edited and corrected the question.

Comment: Hehe. OK. I've updated my answer suggesting another check.

Comment: The only relevant difference is a Valve tag just before closing the Host tag. Could this affect? From the Tomcat documentation I don't see how. The tag is also on my server.xml but it is commented.

Comment: OK. And about the WAR, has it been perfectly transferred to the target machine? Have yoo tried to open it from command line executing `jar ft my.war`?